# RenderTexture crashes with visit operations (Cocos2d-x)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm running into a very strange problem that I didn't have before, maybe I'm too tired and can't see the obvious. I'm creating a RenderTexture and call `visit()` on a draw node while between the `begin()` and `end()` of the render texture:

(this is my unmodified code in the init method of my main Scene)

```
RenderTexture *rt = RenderTexture::create(500, 500);
rt->beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 1);

// [1] Should create a dot in the center of the texture, but...
DrawNode *dot = DrawNode::create();
dot->drawDot(Point(250, 250), 20, Color4F::RED);

// [2] When calling this, the code crashes later, issuing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
// somewhere in the RenderCommand queue.
dot->visit();

rt->end();

rt->setPosition(m_visibleSize.width / 2, m_visibleSize.height / 2);
this->addChild(rt, 100000);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me... I forgot to retain `dot`, so it was released at the end of the block and the RenderCommand queue had a dangling pointer. The solution is to do

```
dot->retain();
```

before calling `visit()`.